# Batch file - delims does not work properly?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a text file and a batch file in the same folder. Their contents are as follows:

---

test.txt contents:

```
one,two
```

---

test.bat contents:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=," %%a in (test.txt) do (echo %%a %%b)
pause >nul
```

---

The output when I run test.bat is:

```
one %b
```

---

Whereas I want and expect the result to be:

```
one two
```

---

I'm not sure what my problem is.

Comment: %%b must be set a something and you are echoing it with out a value. this is you problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"tokens=1,2 delims=,"
```

If not indicated, no more tokens are generated

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. I tried for hours yesterday to figure out the syntax of tokens and delims.